# The touch () command in Linux is asking for an input. What are we supposed to type in there?

Tags: shell, command-line-interface, touch

I was playing around with the `touch` command and as I entered the `touch ()` command, I expected either an error or a new empty file named `()`.
Instead, I got this

```
touch ()
>
```

and it expects me to enter something. 
What is this `touch ()` command doing? What is it for?

Answer (score 3):

With `touch ()`, your shell is expecting you to define a function, something like this:

```sh
touch () {
  echo "Hello"
}
```

(don't do that)

Since `()` are shell metacharacters, if you want to create files with such names, escape them or put them in quotes:

```sh
touch \(\)
touch '()'
touch "()"
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit of an illusion, based on a confusion between types of commands -- some commands are keywords built in to the shell, (like `for` and `if`), some are aliases, (like `ls` and `ll` and `l` on most distros), some are functions, but most are executables.

While there is a `touch` command, (in Ubuntu it activates the executable `/usr/bin/touch`), the code `touch ()` never goes near it.

As [*iBug*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65761835/6136214) notes, the `()` tells the shell that a function is being defined, but since there's no code, the shell prompts the user to enter some.

This isn't specific to the `touch` command however.  The shell will do the same with any command, whether real:

```
 bash ()
 less ()
```

Or made up:

```
foobarbaz()
```

There are exceptions.  For example, if the command is an *alias*, like `ls`, this happens:

```
ls ()
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```